# Angular 10 Dependency Injection fails for extension classes without constructors in unit tests

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, ivy

I have recently upgraded an Angular app from version 8 to version 10. In the app I make use of extension classes like the following pattern:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyBaseClass {
  constructor(myDependencyService: MyDependencyService,...) {}
}

@Injectable()
export class MyExtensionClass extends MyBaseClass {
  // no explicit constructor in extension class
}
```

The application runs as expected, with all dependencies correctly injected into the base class constructor on instantiation of the extension class. However, when unit tests are run, the dependency injection falls apart, and all of the arguments to the base class constructor are undefined.

Looking at the compiled source code in the browser dev tools, the Angular-generated factory for the extension class looks completely different when executing tests than it is when running the application: when running the tests, the compiled factory passes no parameters when creating the extension class.

I have followed all the recommendations for upgrading to the Ivy compiler, and all classes that use DI are decorated and working correctly in the app. Is there some peculiarity that causes different compilation results when executing tests? Have I missed some configuration change that affects the unit tests?

**Update:** I've pinpointed this DI issue to the code coverage reporter. When I remove the coverage option the dependencies are correctly injected. There seems to be some conflict between the coverage reporter and the Angular compiler. I'm using karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter version 3.0.2.

Comment: Not on the problem but I'd recommend not upgrading between 2 or more major versions. Uprade to 9 first, followed by 10.  This also helps iron out issues to the changes made in only one version, instead of 2.

Comment: I should have mentioned in the description that I did just as you suggested. I prepared the upgrade according to Angular recommendations, first upgrading to Angular 9, then to Angular 10. I didn't run the test suite in between.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a known issue when targeting es2015 (or higher) in tsconfig.spec.json: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14860.

Workaround is to target es5.